# Taking means of more than one value

Tags: r

I'm trying to take the means of `diversity` by `LOC_ID` although, I would also like the mean of `HOW_MANY` by `LOC_ID`. When I use this code:

```
e <- aggregate(diversity ~ LOC_ID + season + year + POSTCODE + X + Y+ LONGITUDE + LATITUDE + HOW_MANY, e, mean)
```

The means aren't properly taken as `LOC_ID` should match the seasons, and there should be a unqiue locality per season.

Reproducible code:

```
structure(list(LOC_ID = c("LOC1300605020", "LOC1300605020", "LOC1153084541859", 
"LOC1153084541859", "LOC1049970899816", "LOC1049970899816", "LOC1300617408", 
"LOC1300617408", "LOC676185", "LOC676185", "LOC996421", "LOC1039789", 
"LOC696817", "LOC691949", "LOC691949", "LOC1419870616457", "LOC675786", 
"LOC675786", "LOC675872", "LOC675872", "LOC1360873032512", "LOC1360873032512", 
"LOC1300602196", "LOC1300602196", "LOC726816", "LOC726816", "LOC1022032", 
"LOC614488", "LOC1300613011", "LOC575706", "LOC575706", "LOC661691", 
"LOC1048553080056", "LOC1163128", "LOC1163128", "LOC1300605079", 
"LOC1300605079", "LOC661933", "LOC627857", "LOC627857", "LOC1049318", 
"LOC1049318", "LOC1083442", "LOC891500", "LOC1300602161", "LOC1300602161", 
"LOC1300604915", "LOC1300604915", "LOC1300612568", "LOC1300612568"
), season = c("Summer", "Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Summer", 
"Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Summer", 
"Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Summer", "Winter", 
"Summer", "Winter", "Summer", "Summer", "Winter", "Winter", "Summer", 
"Summer", "Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Winter", "Summer", "Winter", 
"Summer", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Summer", 
"Winter", "Summer", "Winter"), year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014), POSTCODE = c("IP22 4BE", "IP22 4BE", "IP22 4BD", 
"IP22 4BD", "IP22 4YW", "IP22 4YW", "IP22 5SB", "IP22 5SB", "IP24 3HG", 
"IP24 3HG", "IP24 2YR", "IP24 3LR", "IP24 3NF", "IP24 1JF", "IP24 1JF", 
"IP22 2DZ", "NR16 2DX", "NR16 2DX", "NR16 2NF", "NR16 2NF", "NR34 0HT", 
"NR34 0HT", "NR34 0EQ", "NR34 0EQ", "NR34 0HJ", "NR34 0HJ", "NR16 1NA", 
"NR16 1NA", "NR32 5QW", "NR17 1QJ", "NR17 1QJ", "IP26 4NT", "NR15 1SZ", 
"NR15 1TS", "NR15 1TS", "NR17 1LL", "NR17 1LL", "NR17 1TP", "NR15 1HS", 
"NR15 1HS", "NR31 9RN", "NR31 9RN", "IP26 5LH", "IP26 5LG", "IP25 6QU", 
"IP25 6QU", "PE38 0JE", "PE38 0JE", "NR14 8LH", "NR14 8LH"), 
    X = c(611179L, 611179L, 610991L, 610991L, 610987L, 610987L, 
    609674L, 609674L, 585759L, 585759L, 587313L, 586391L, 585707L, 
    587221L, 587221L, 610986L, 603714L, 603714L, 599513L, 599513L, 
    640565L, 640565L, 642642L, 642642L, 638712L, 638712L, 611265L, 
    611265L, 647828L, 604044L, 604044L, 573386L, 622927L, 622766L, 
    622766L, 601782L, 601782L, 599128L, 628213L, 628213L, 652424L, 
    652424L, 575072L, 574872L, 590616L, 590616L, 562144L, 562144L, 
    623658L, 623658L), Y = c(279472L, 279472L, 279827L, 279827L, 
    280059L, 280059L, 281130L, 281130L, 281694L, 281694L, 282033L, 
    282331L, 282941L, 283837L, 283837L, 285424L, 285789L, 285789L, 
    286475L, 286475L, 291966L, 291966L, 293875L, 293875L, 294141L, 
    294141L, 294021L, 294021L, 296985L, 295466L, 295466L, 294750L, 
    297223L, 297644L, 297644L, 296769L, 296769L, 296715L, 299066L, 
    299066L, 300312L, 300312L, 297095L, 297369L, 298939L, 298939L, 
    298440L, 298440L, 301564L, 301564L), LONGITUDE = c(1.1008304, 
    1.1008304, 1.0982962, 1.0982962, 1.0983835, 1.0983835, 1.0797928, 
    1.0797928, 0.72912822, 0.72912822, 0.75213221, 0.7387612, 
    0.7290562, 0.75179017, 0.75179017, 1.1017473, 0.99517475, 
    0.99517475, 0.93387689, 0.93387689, 1.5406583, 1.5406583, 
    1.5725647, 1.5725647, 1.5149876, 1.5149876, 1.1112851, 1.1112851, 
    1.651099, 1.0059407, 1.0059407, 0.55423544, 1.2849555, 1.2828683, 
    1.2828683, 0.97344091, 0.97344091, 0.9343368, 1.3640025, 
    1.3640025, 1.7212069, 1.7212069, 0.58029424, 0.57749237, 
    0.81028694, 0.81028694, 0.39049374, 0.39049374, 1.298635, 
    1.298635), LATITUDE = c(52.372568, 52.372568, 52.375827, 
    52.375827, 52.377912, 52.377912, 52.38803, 52.38803, 52.401724, 
    52.401724, 52.404238, 52.407229, 52.412939, 52.420469, 52.420469, 
    52.426073, 52.432105, 52.432105, 52.439812, 52.439812, 52.472574, 
    52.472574, 52.488784, 52.488784, 52.492903, 52.492903, 52.503138, 
    52.503138, 52.514358, 52.518859, 52.518859, 52.523037, 52.527239, 
    52.531083, 52.531083, 52.531398, 52.531398, 52.531889, 52.541592, 
    52.541592, 52.542097, 52.542097, 52.543558, 52.546083, 52.554901, 
    52.554901, 52.559639, 52.559639, 52.565899, 52.565899), HOW_MANY = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), diversity = c(0.735781131447024, 
    0.701820404068141, 0.763725747125258, 0.744920095166856, 
    0.813814611634834, 0.774707565546224, 0.787617981793466, 
    0.773223903459372, 0.758751874243701, 0.782236694925942, 
    0.929875821767714, 0.722222222222222, 0.839166666666667, 
    0.853773335501946, 0.814723946917023, 0.7421875, 0.856227365323676, 
    0.786939474130527, 0.749753145020342, 0.80776612298888, 0.76486845551189, 
    0.766327932310796, 0.643198255747736, 0.625260182192689, 
    0.725510470709725, 0.71518504859771, 0.830449826989619, 0.681818181818182, 
    0.8, 0.67353688088398, 0.792853918307987, 0.851239669421488, 
    0.766111449949709, 0.816431076046461, 0.775975420094361, 
    0.724416899520566, 0.741425542132917, 0.855820869913352, 
    0.714194140511574, 0.791330805145525, 0.687309989269034, 
    0.70891452402816, 0.876710207012938, 0.759850157758368, 0.771849754898334, 
    0.820690687544672, 0.843537414965986, 0.78003327480109, 0.800033565151083, 
    0.723197864958197)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: IN the data showed, HOW_MANY are all 0 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `aggregate`, we can use `cbind`

```
 aggregate(cbind(diversity, HOW_MANY) ~ LOC_ID +
     season + year + POSTCODE + X + Y+ LONGITUDE + LATITUDE, e, mean)
```

---

If the grouping is ony by 'LOC_ID', do a second `aggregate` and then `merge`

```
e1 <- aggregate(diversity ~ LOC_ID + season + year + POSTCODE + X + 
     Y+ LONGITUDE + LATITUDE + HOW_MANY, e, mean)
e2 <- aggregate(HOW_MANY ~ LOC_ID, e, mean)
merge(e1, e2)
```

Comment: Great suggestions, thank you! I tried grouping them with a logical operator like `&`, unfortunately it does not work as expected.

Comment: @Lime Can you show your expected output. thanks.  I noticed that you are overwriting the original data 'e' with the `aggregate` summary output

Comment: I have noticed that `merge` works perfectly well when `HOW_MANY` is removed from the first dataframe, and the same chain of columns in the first then used in the second with `HOW_MANY` as the `x` variable.

Comment: @Lime Or in the `merge`, you could specify `by = "LOC_ID"` because otherwise, it picks the columns that are common automatically in `by`